# sql 2012 - return table row based on values looped from another table - is this possible? Views Function

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I have done this with vb code but would like it returned as a view from a if possible.

The `main table`, has `table_id, table_value1, table_value2, table_value3` for example
There is another table called `history` with references to `table_id, history_id, history_index, table_ref, new_value, old_value`

Example data from `maintable`

```
table_id  table_value1  table_value2  table_value3
1         fred          dummydata     moredummydata
```

`history table`:

```
history_id  history_index  table_id  table_ref      new_value      old_Value
5           4              2         table_value2   bert           alpha
4           3              1         table_value1   test           new
3           3              1         table_value3   moredummydata  dummy 
2           2              1         table_value3   dummy
1           1              1         table_value1   new
```

What i want to happen, if i provide `table_id` to function, it obtains the row from `main` table and then works through the history table descending to the `history_index` provided.

For example if `table_id = 1` it should return a table with

```
table_id  history_index table_value1  table_value2  table_value3
1         3             test          dummydata     moredummydata
1         2             new           dummydata     dummy
1         1             new           dummydata
```

Working with a copy of the `maintable` row, i want it to apply the following:

Starting at the highest `history_id`, i want it to loop through to the `history_index` provided:

1. At `history_id` = 5, it will apply `old_value` to the field specified in `table_ref`.  In this case it will update `table_value1` with the value 'test'.
2. Then it will move down to `history_id` = 4 and apply new_value for the field specified in table_ref.

So my question is, best way of looping from history table desending and updating temporary maintable row with field specified in table_ref with the old_value then the new_value for the last entry.

The main idea is that i have a table with 20-30 fields, that i want to record each time there is a change to a field. Or is there an easier way i haven't thought of?

sql fiddle showing 2 databases http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d5a71/3

```
CREATE TABLE main
(
table_id int NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,          
table_value1 varchar(50),
table_value2 varchar(50),
table_value3 varchar(50)
);
INSERT INTO main VALUES ('test','dummydata','moredummydata');
CREATE TABLE history
(
history_id int NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
history_index int,
table_id int,
table_ref varchar(50),
new_value varchar(50),
old_Value varchar(50)
);

INSERT INTO history VALUES (1,1,'table_value1','new','');
INSERT INTO history VALUES (2,1,'table_value3','dummy', '');
INSERT INTO history VALUES (3,1,'table_value3','moredummydata', 'dummy');
INSERT INTO history VALUES (3,1,'table_value1','test','new');
INSERT INTO history VALUES (4,1,'table_value1','fred','test');
INSERT INTO history VALUES (5,2,'table_value2','bert','alpha');
```

Comment: Your question doesn't have enough detail for anybody to offer a lot of assistance. Please provide us some ddl and sample data along with desired output so we can help. sqlfiddle.com would be a great place to start.

Comment: Sorry, i have updated the question with more details.  Thanks for the link for sqlfiddle.com

Comment: Oye. You have a real challenge here. You have a history table in the anti-pattern of EAV (entity attribute value). This type of design pattern has their place but as you are discovering a history or audit table makes this incredibly complicated. You might be able to do this in a single query but the performance is going to be awful. The fiddle you created would not cause any change in main. The values are all the most "current" as stated by the rules.

Comment: Thanks, thats the problem, i made a solution with entity framework with c# but wanted to try my hand at functions in sql but lack the ability :(  If i scrap my history table, what would be the best way of storing changes made in the maintable?  I am using 2012 so maybe same time and use the built in change tracker, just working out how i would retrieve the old data.. hmmm

Answer (score 1):

OK. Here is a way you can do this. This is somewhat complicated but this will build a dynamic sql statement to execute. For now the string will not be executed so you can test this out and see what it is doing. If you are satisfied you can uncomment the last line and it will execute the statement. There are a number of things going on in here. Make sure you understand what this is doing. I can help you understand if you get stumped.

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max);

with SortedValues as
(
    select table_id
        , table_ref + ' = ''' + REPLACE(new_value, '''', '''''') + '''' as NewValue
        , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by table_id, table_ref order by history_id desc) as RowNum
    from history
)
, UpdateCols as
(
    select top 1 table_id
        , STUFF((
            select nv.NewValue + ', ' as [text()]
            from SortedValues nv
            where RowNum = 1
        for xml path(''), type).value('.','varchar(max)'), 1, 0, '') as UpdateStatement
    from SortedValues
    where RowNum = 1
)

select @SQL = 'Update main set ' + LEFT(UpdateStatement, LEN(UpdateStatement) - 1) + ' where table_id = ' + cast(table_id as varchar(4))
from UpdateCols

select @SQL
--exec sp_executesql @SQL
```

--EDIT--

With my new understanding this is how it would look. Please note, this will not run in sqlfiddle. Not really sure why. It runs just fine in SSMS though.

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max) = '';

with SortedValues as
(
    select table_id
        , table_ref + ' = ''' + REPLACE(new_value, '''', '''''') + '''' as NewValue
        , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by table_id, table_ref order by history_id desc) as RowNum
    from history
)
, UpdateCols as
(
    select table_id
        , STUFF((
            select nv.NewValue + ', ' as [text()]
            from SortedValues nv
            where RowNum = 1
            and nv.table_id = sv.table_id
        for xml path(''), type).value('.','varchar(max)'), 1, 0, '') as UpdateStatement
    from SortedValues sv
    where RowNum = 1
    group by table_id
)

select @SQL = @SQL + 'Update main set ' + LEFT(UpdateStatement, LEN(UpdateStatement) - 1) + ' where table_id = ' + cast(table_id as varchar(4)) + ';'
from UpdateCols

select @SQL
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, am i correct in understanding that that the `updatecols` function uses `sortedvalues` which is a list of history rows.  The `updatecol` loops through and creates a dynamic string. a little lost at the xml path.  I do not want it updating the live main table and want it to update a temporary row or view?  I cannot see where i would provide a history_id value to work down to?

Comment: You could easily change the update statement to hit a different table. Do you understand the STUFF part? Basically what I did here was to take each row and shove them into a single column. SortedValues uses Row_Number to get a row number for each row with partitioning. This can't be referenced within the same query which is why I used a second cte so we can get only the first one. In other words we will get one row for each history_id. I think there is an issue here though if there is more than 1 table_id. I didn't have data to test with but it should be an easy modification.

Comment: Thanks, i understand how to update different table and just about understand the stuff part.  Apologies i forgot a column out of my history table which i use for working down the list of history items.  For each history_index that is different it should return a row?  sorry if asking too much!

Comment: The first cte does return a row for each history_id. It also numbers each of them so we know which one is the most current.

Comment: Thanks.  Ive changed the question as i want the result to return a table as described above. Hope it makes sense

Comment: So just take the first 2 ctes from this. You just want the rows where RowNum = 1.

Comment: i have put your code at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0c0ab/3 it returns table_id = 2 as well when i just want table_id =1.  How would i return seperate rows, would i need to insert into a temporary row?  Appreicate your help on this.

Comment: Please see my recent update. I think that is what you are looking for. Anything else from here is just some minor modifications to this which you should be able to handle.

Comment: Apologies, im not describing what i need correctly.  Thanks for the update, i only want table_id 1 return but 3 rows returned as above with the changes made each time.  Guess i would need to start with a copy of the table row, then apply changes and then create a copy of that row and apply more changes???

Comment: Why do you want to do these updates piecemeal like that? What you are describing now is a loop. This is not a good thing to in sql server. If you want you can get the dynamically created update statement 1 row at a time.

Comment: agree loop not good idea, one row at a time would be good.  I would request from my asp site a history_index and table_id, so it would return a version of table_row with all the changes made since.

Comment: That is pretty much what it is defined. All you would need to do is to add a parameter and an additional predicate to the original query in the first cte. This would then return all the values for that history_index exactly as you are describing.

Comment: thanks, ive updated my sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0c0ab/23, as added ive added `from history where table_id = 1 and history_index >= 3` but it doesnt return the desired result.  It should return table_value1 = **'new'**, table_value3 = 'moredummydata'.  It should apply the old field value whilst descending down to the wanted index and then apply the new fields.  Sorry to keep bugging.

Comment: Take out the @ SQL variable and just do the select. select 'Update main set ' + LEFT(UpdateStatement, LEN(UpdateStatement) - 1) + ' where table_id = ' + cast(table_id as varchar(4))
from UpdateCols

Comment: sorry its the table_value1 should return new but it doesnt.  Thats why i said about it should be applyng the old_value and then when it is at history_index = 3 then apply the new value?

Comment: sorry table_value1 should be test when looking for history_index =3 and not fred